# PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials yields PrincipalOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have the following code:

```
using( var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Machine ) )
{
    if (context.ValidateCredentials("nonexistinguser", "pwd"))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

that yields `PrincipalOperationException` on the line with

```
if (context.ValidateCredentials("nonexistinguser", "pwd"))
```

with the following text

> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

This just doesn't make any sense.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and this using is all of your code? is this code part of an object? maybe you got multiple objects and each try to connect at the same time

Comment: @WiiMaxx: Nope, that's the beginning of `Main()`.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows Server 2008 R2 using also ContextType.Machine

Comment: That happens to me, when I start the web app in my Wix-Setup (started setup as administrator) and at the web app I try to login